# ¿Cómo hacer un Select en un Datatable con campos tipo DateTime?

Tags: c#, datatable

Tengo un DataTable con dos campos "BirthDay" y "HireDay" del tipo DateTime, y quiero filtrar las filas que correspondan a dos fechas determinadas.

Siguiendo las instrucciones de [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934615/c-sharp-datatable-select-statement-with-dates) armé mi query de la siguiente manera:

```
DateTime bday = new DateTime(2016, 8, 9);
DateTime hday = new DateTime(2016, 8, 10);

String query = 
String.Concat("BirthDay=#", Convert.ToString(bday.Date), "# or HireDay=#", Convert.ToString(bday.Date), "#");
DataRow[] encontrados = miDatatable.Select(query);
```

EL valor de la variable `query` es:

```
"BirthDay=#09/08/2016 12:00:00 a.m.# or HireDay=#10/08/2016 12:00:00 a.m.#"
```

Y al ejecutar mi aplicación me lanza esta excepción:

Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.FormatException' en mscorlib.dll

Información adicional: La cadena no se reconoce como DateTime válido. Hay una palabra desconocida al inicio del índice 24.

En cambio, si cambio manualmente el valor de la variable `query` a:

```
"BirthDay=#09/08/2016# or HireDay=#10/08/2016#"
```

no me tira excepción, pero ya no me devuelve ninguna fila, a pesar de que sí tengo fechas en los campos "BirthDay" y "HireDay" iguales al 9 de agosto del 2016.

No he encontrado cómo realizar la conversión de fecha para que no lance excepciones y me devuelva la data correcta.
Mi configuración de hora y fecha es es-pe.

**Edit:** sip, también intenté con `bday.ToShortDateString()` y tampoco me devuelve filas.

**Otro  edit:** probé la solución de Leandro Tuttini y funcionó (me devuelve las filas correctas)... a pesar de que el valor de `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` y la configuración regional de mi sistema operativo es la misma: `es-PE`. Lo curioso es que si le pongo la configuración de fecha de `es-PE`:

```
string query =  string.Format("BirthDay=#{0:dd/MM/yyyy}# or HireDay=#{1:dd//MMyyyy}#", bday, hday);
```

No me devuelve ninguna fila. Posiblemente los Datatables sólo reconocen la cultura `en-US`.
Estoy usando .Net 3.5.

Comment: `bday.ToShortDateString()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta algo como esto

```
DateTime bday = new DateTime(2016, 8, 9);
DateTime hday = new DateTime(2016, 8, 10);

string query =  string.Format("BirthDay=#{0:MM/dd/yyyy}# or HireDay=#{1:MM/dd/yyyy}#", bday, hday);

DataRow[] encontrados = miDatatable.Select(query);
```

veras que la fecha tiene un formato sin fecha, ademas suas el string.Format() para posicionar cada valor dentro del string que usas de filtro

El hecho de no devolver valores creo que viene por el formato de la fecha, quizas un formato dd/MM/yyyy no lo reconoce, por eso en el ejemplo que puse usea el que utiliza la cultura en-US en donde define MM/dd/yyyy